# Looking for a childrens book with siblings and only one could see the fantasy world (not spiderwick)

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read a book or maybe series when I was a kid that had 3 siblings that visit another world, or see more of this world.

- One can see this world
- One can with one eye but not the other
- One can't see the world

I think they had different eye colours depending on what they could see

It may have involved a cat?

I know it's not the Spiderwick Chronicles.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Answer (score 4):

Possibly [The Eidolon Chronicles](https://www.goodreads.com/series/81097-eidolon), by Jane Johnson. The boy with heterochromia is Ben, and his sisters are Ellie (with no magic) and Alice (with magic). The cat would be Iggy, who is from the parallel world (known as the Secret Country).

Comment: i think this is it!! thanks!

Comment: @beth - Don't forget to upvote and press the 'accept' button next to this answer